# Program to minimize certain programs only

Tags: gratis, windows-7, window-manager, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a free program that allows me to press a keyboard shortcut, and if certain programs are open (ie. not minimized already), then *only them* should get minimized.

So, if I had Skype, Microsoft Word and Google Chrome open on my screen, then when I press a shortcut, only Microsoft Word should get minimized (according to pre-defined settings).

I hope I make sense!

Requirements:

- free
- keyboard shortcut
- has settings for which programs should be minimized

Comment: Asked this from [this](http://superuser.com/questions/782489/minimize-some-windows-but-not-all-via-keyboard-shortcut) question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (Free, open-source, Windows), something along the lines of:

```
MinimizeProcess(ExeFile)
{
Process, Exist, %ExeFile%
PID = %ErrorLevel%
if (PID = 0)
{
  Return
}

IfWinExist, ahk_pid %PID%
{
  WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%
}
}

!^l::
MinimizeProcess("notepad++.exe")
MinimizeProcess("notepad.exe")
; list all your programs that you want to minimize here
return
```

But the script needs some improvements (namely fixing issue with `WinMinimize, ahk_pid %PID%` and making sure that all windows of a process gets minimized).

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#Create . Right now the script isn't working on my computer, so don't expect much from it... if anyone knows what the issue is, I'm curious. But in theory AHK should be able to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Seems like the issue I have my be specific to my computer (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24724075/395857), so it might work better for you.

Comment: OK, I'll be able to test it when I am on my Windows laptop.

Comment: @ṧнʊß Thanks :) yeah I wish I could provide a working script but right now the bug is quite a puzzle to me!

Comment: Thanks, it works for me! It's strange how it doesn't work for you...

Comment: @ṧнʊß Cool glad it works for you. Yeah I would guess that there is some differences with some programs I have: I'll try to kill some + test in VM to see how it goes. I'll add another comment if I find the issue. It seems like the root of the issue is that `!^b::WinMinimize, ahk_pid 9156` does not even work (when 9156 is a valid PID) :/